# Gum up Vs Gunk up

Tags: word-usage, usage

Are these two phrasal verbs interchangeable?

> Eggnog **gunks the steamer up**.
>
> Eggnog **gums the steamer up.**

And if the filters are clogged due to dust particles in an AC etc:

> The filters are **gunked up**.
>
> The filters are **gummed up**.

Or will "clogged" be used here?

And what about a car's engine?

> The engine is **gunked up.**
>
> The engine is **gummed up.**

Comment: _Gunk_ is an informal word; you wouldn't use it in technical writing.

Comment: The filters are indeed **clogged**.